# How to compute the first derived direct image along an open immersion, for the fppf sheaf represented by a multiplicative group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-functors

Let $S=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, $s=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ and $\eta=\mathrm{Spec}(K)$, where $R$ is a d.v.r. with fraction field $K$. Let $j:\eta\rightarrow S$

Now how to compute the sheaf $R^1j_*(\mathbb{G}_{m,\eta})$ in the fppf topology?

The case for etale topology is zero by considering the stalks and use the Hilbert 90.

Comment: is there any general way to compute such staff in flat topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that (equation) 5.2 and Appendice 11.7 of "Le Groupe de Brauer, III" imply that the cohomology for the \'etale topology equals the cohomology for the fppf topology.

Comment: @Jason Starr: thanks a lot for the reference. The condition (L) is satisfied obviously for $j_*\mathbb{G}_m$. the condition (R) is less obvious, in particular what should be the open subfunctor? Is it $\mathbb{G}_m$. 

Comment: @Jason Starr: what is the definition of an open subfunctor?

Comment: I am not suggesting to apply Theorem 11.7 to $j_*\mathbb{G}_m$, but rather to $\mathbb{G}_m$, where condition (R) is tautological (the open subfunctor is the entire functor).

Grothendieck proves that for any scheme $X$, for every integer $p$, the natural map `$H^p(X_{\text{\'et}},\mathbb{G}_m) \to H^p(X_{\text{fppf}},\mathbb{G}_m)$` is an isomorphism.  I claim that this implies that for every morphism $f:X\to Y$, also the natural map
`$R^p f_*\mathbb{G}_{m,\text{\'et}} \to R^p f_*\mathbb{G}_{m,\text{fppf}}$ is an isomorphism, i.e., the derived etale and fppf pushforwards agree ...

Comment: ... To go from Grothendieck's theorem to the claim, use Prop. 5.1, Exp. V, SGA 4.

Comment: @Jason Starr: I see what you meant. But the natural map should be $R^p f_*\mathbb{G}_{m,\text{et}} \to u_{Y*}R^p f_*\mathbb{G}_{m,\text{fppf}}$, where $u_Y:Y_{\text{fppf}}\rightarrow Y_{\text{et}}$. Then $u_{Y*}R^p f_*\mathbb{G}_{m,\text{fppf}}=0$ provided $R^p f_*\mathbb{G}_{m,\text{et}}$, But this doesn't imply that $R^p f_*\mathbb{G}_{m,\text{fppf}}=0$ 

Comment: @Jason Starr: Have I gotten your point?

Comment: @Heer: Which sites are you working with?  If you are working with the big sites, then I believe that `$u_{Y*}R^pf_*\mathbb{G}_{m,fppf}$` has the same sections on every $Y$-scheme as `$R^pf_*\mathbb{G}_{m,fppf}$`.  If you are working with the small \'etale site, then do you really care about the value of `$R^pf_*\mathbb{G}_{m,fppf}$` except on \'etale $Y$-schemes?

Comment: @ Jason Starr: I consider the big etale site, and I think now I am convinced. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jason Starr: however i got confused with something else. I guess the relation between big fppf site and big etale site is: they have the same "opens", but in the fppf site you have more coverings, so it's stronger for a contravariant functor being a fppf sheaf that being an etale sheaf. And if the functor is already a fppf sheaf, then it has the same section as its direct image as an eatle sheaf.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of seeing this. Since $R$ is a dvr, any fppf covering 
can be refined to a connected cover $p:U\to Spec(R)$ where $U=Spec(A)$ and $A$ is a faithfully flat $R$ algebra of finite type. Also, for our purposes, we might as well replace $R$ with its strict henselization. Now taking generic hyperplane sections of $A$ through a point over $m_R$ refines the covering $p:Spec(A)→Spec(R)$ to a finite, faithfully flat cover $\overline p:Spec(A/(f_1,...,f_n))\to Spec(R)$ which we may assume is connected. But there are no non-trivial line bundles on a connected algebra that is finite over a field.